# CGContext: Bitmap Background Color: Cannot set to white: IOS

Tags: ios, bitmap, core-graphics, background-color, cgcontext

I'm trying to modify some simple "create a paint app" code to have a white background colour, rather than the black that it is set to. The example code is located at:

http://blog.effectiveui.com/?p=8105

I've tried setting self.backgroundcolor = [UIColor whiteColor], also [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill] with no effect. I'm missing something very basic due to my inexperience.

Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've added a couple of lines to the drawRect that should do it for you. You were on the right track, but when you set the color to white, you actually need to then fill the paintView rectangle with it:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(touch != nil){
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        //clear background color to white
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        hue += 0.005;
        if(hue > 1.0) hue = 0.0;
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:0.7 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 15);

        CGPoint lastPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

The reason view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; didn't work is that any view that implements drawRect ignores the backgroundColor property, and the programmer is responsible for drawing the whole view contents, including the background.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I tried this, and for some reason it did not work. There are several examples of the paint app in the page at the end of the link, and I'm using the more advanced version that produces nice curved lines using bezier functions. From the post below I think that I need to set the cachecontext to white a the start?

Comment: If you are using the last example from the link, you probably need to put the two lines I added above in the - drawToCache method instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the part you've missed is this section of PaintView:

```
 - (BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {

    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (cacheBitmap == NULL){
        return NO;
    }
    cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmap, size.width, size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    return YES;
}
```

That creates a single context, which it calls a cache, that all subsequent touches are drawn to. In the view's `drawRect:` it simply copies the cache to the output.

One of the flags it provides — `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst` — specifies that the cached context has no alpha channel. So when it's drawn there's no chance for the background to show through regardless of any other factor; the black comes from the cacheContext just as if you'd painted black with your finger.

So what you really want to do is to fill the cacheContext with white before you begin. You can either do that by memsetting the cacheBitmap array, since you've explicitly told the context where to store its data, or you can use a suitable `CGContextFillRect` to the cacheContext.

Comment: Hi Tommy, thanks for this. If I wanted to go down the memmsetting route, can you tell me how I'd force cacheBitmap array to white? Cheers.

Comment: @LeeBarringer you'd throw in a quick `memset(cacheBitmap, 255, bitmapByteCount)` anywhere after you've malloc'd cacheBitmap. White can be set with a simple memset because you've explicitly dictated where the bitmap context should store its pixels and white is a colour with all channels set to the same value.

Comment: Tommy, that fixed it a treat. Thank you very much. I'm infact trying to make a simple 'signature capture' feature for my app ... so black on white is perfect. Cheers.

Comment: Can you Please tell me what to do if i want paint view to be clear color so that image on view behind paint view is visible  and gives a look like painting on the image

Comment: @Dinesh Kaushik

Yes you can - do this when you setup the Cached Context:


 cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate ( cacheBitmap
            , size.width
            , size.height
            , 8
            , bitmapBytesPerRow
            , CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            , kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
           );

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the source code but have a clear background to the image you are creating and 'inking' on - when you setup the cachedBitmap, do it like this.

```
cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate ( cacheBitmap
                                      , size.width
                                      , size.height
                                      , 8
                                      , bitmapBytesPerRow
                                      , CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                                      , kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
                                     );
```

That way, when you set your stroke color for the 'ink' only the 'ink' will be painted. Ensure that the drawing View also has a background color of clearColor, and opaque set to NO.

This means that the view that the drawing view has been added to will now be visible underneath or through this drawing view. Therefore set the background color of that view to whatever you want or alternatively, put a UIImageView behind the drawing view and voila! You can insert an image for lined paper or graph paper or whatever you want!